# chmod alternative working on ancestor paths? use case: g+x on all ancestors of a directory

Tags: permissions, chmod, acl

There are some cases, where you might want to provide, e.g., "+x" permission to a group or others on a deep directory. It may not be overly complicated to apply this to every ancestor directory by means of some shell script, I am wondering whether a direct command exists, though.

Use cases, e.g.,:

1. ~/public_html (chmod o+x)
2. /var/run/user/1001/pulse/native (chmod g+x)

---

1. What means of setting up a complete "path permission" is available? (could be "chmod --ancestors g+x [deep path]")
2. What means of access validation is available? (could be "chkmod g+x:audio [deep path]")